# Azure Data Factory, table storage copy Binary data results in System.Byte[] output

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-table-storage, data-migration, azure-storage-account

We are moving large amounts of data from one table store to another table store in other region and subscription.

I have set up a pipeline for copying the data in Azure Data Factory, which seemed like the easiest and fastest route to go.

All data seem to be able to copy correctly except one column with Binary data.

I have set up a mapping like this:
[image: mapping details]

But the resulting Value is the string "System.Byte[]":

[image: Resulting table]

Source table column:

[image: Source Table]

---

This does not seem like intended behaviour, and wonder if I have missed something or there is a bug with this type of mapping.

Comment: Binary data in Azure Table Storage is saved as Base64 encoded string. Have you tried using "String" as the data type instead of "Byte[]"?

Comment: @GauravMantri The datatype is definately binary in the table, and I need it to stay as such.
I can try to transfer it as string, and see if i can transform it later, but that seems like a cumbersome workaround.

As you can see here in the azure documentation the Table storage type "Binary" should be mapped to the "Byte[]" type. 
[Type documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage?tabs=data-factory#data-type-mapping-for-azure-table)

Comment: @GauravMantri I tried mapping as string -> string also, and I ended up with the same result "System.Byte[]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem.

In this [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#data-type-mapping) explaining the way of data transformation I found out there was a "legacy" conversion experience. To enable this experience you should set `"typeConversion": false` in the JSON. After I did this, all my `Byte[]` data was copied correctly.

I have to mention that I use custom column mapping in my solution. Maybe this can help you too.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same approach at my end.

**Mapping:**

[image]

**Source Table Storage:**

[image]
**Sink table Storage:**

[image]

I am able to get the Same datatype same as the source as you can see from the above source and sink azure table storage.

Try reloading your ADF pipeline and check if your issue is fixed or if the issue still persist you can  [Create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request)

Comment: After more digging I have found that this only happens if the Binary data is Null/missing for some of the rows. Try inserting 1000 rows where the property is missing, then one row with binary data, to maybe replicate my problem.

I tried transfering only a subset of the data using a query where i knew I had Content, and it was able to transfer successfully. I then tried transfering the rest and it still failed.

Comment: @Jim-AlexanderBergerGundersen As you can see the demo 1 even have a NULL value in in its row data.

Comment: My working theory right now is that it uses the first N rows to infer some types. So you would need N rows with null data to replicate my issue. The tables im working with have potentially millions of rows where only half of them have any data in the content column. I have created a ticket with my issue, will update here when I hear anything